# Lambda: Is it better to download multiple files in one function or separate functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I'm wanting to download many images from S3 in a Lambda function (+- 500 images).

Is it better to do this in a single Lambda function or should I create a separate Lambda function to download a single file and call that 500 times?

Comment: One thing you may consider is that the HTML spec is changing in the near future to allow more than 6 background threads, so ... dunno if that affects you or not, but I'd suspect that it would, and that it would be more efficient to let the system manage the streams rather than queuing them yourself.  Have you tested anything?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the files after you've downloaded them. Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to do it in a single Lambda function that is called 500 times. The reason being is that the maximum execution time for a Lambda Function is currently 5 minutes. With that many images (and depending on any subsequent processing performed on them), it is likely that your execution time might exceed the maximum.

You also might run into memory constraints if you tried downloading all 500 images during a single lambda function execution. I believe that Lambda supports at most 1536 MegaBytes of memory. Storing all 500 images on disk during the run is also likely not possible as you are limited to 512 MB in the /tmp directory.